# Change connection string in MembershipProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I am using `MVC 2`and I cannot find a way to change my default connection string in `MembershipProvider`.

My Web.Config

```
    <connectionstrings>
       <add name="ConnectionString.SQL Server (SqlClient)" connectionstring="Data     
                  Source=Mysource\testdb-20121109102135.mdf;Initial Catalog=testdb-
                  20121109102135;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" 
                  providername="System.Data.SqlClient" />
     </connectionstrings>
```

Whereas my default connection string generated is

```
     data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true
```

How can I change it ??

Thank you All

Comment: Do you mean to change programmatically? How about COnfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings?

Comment: I have already tried that in connection strings

Comment: Why you dont change "connectionStringName" for this membershipProvider in Web.Config? The problem is not clean enough for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your pain as changing membership provider details can be very vexing .Here all the magic is in `Web.config` file in the **Root folder**. All you need to do is add this code  to your file after `<configuration>` .

```
   <connectionStrings>
<add name="MySqlConnection" connectionString="Data 
  Source=MySqlServer;Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;Integrated
  Security=SSPI;" />
```

and after `<authentication>` add

```
   <authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
<membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
         connectionStringName="MySqlConnection" applicationName="MyApplication" 
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" 
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" requiresUniqueEmail="true" 
         passwordFormat="Hashed"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

And Voila! it works.....

For more information please refer [Configuring an ASP.NET Application to Use Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e9y4s5t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)